# Is this possible to use lwuit.Dialog with javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas in wireless toolkit 2.5.2?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-dialog

I am using `javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas` for drawing my string on the screen. But I also need one dialog window for some purpose. So I am using `lwuit` package (`com.sun.lwuit.Dialog`) for showing dialog window when key pressing.

So in my program I just included that package and create the object of the Dialog box. While running my application, it is terminated unexpectedly.

I just included the following lines...

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
import com.sun.lwuit.Dialog;

public class Mycanvas extends Canvas implements CommandListener
{
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    //some other remaining codes for my canvas...
}
```

So, is it possible to show `lwuit` dialog window with `lcdui` canvas?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's possible but it will increase size of the app significantly. Whenever you need your dialog you can init LWUIT Display and use LWUIT Forms and Dialogs.

I would better to implement some really simple Dialog ourselves. It's not really much work. Or use another third party solution.

Comment: ok If it is possible then why my program terminated unexpectedly?... enlighten me on this?...

Answer (score 1):

My Idea is create an user defined Item which extends from CustomItem for dialog.But it is difficult to code the complete implementation.Better u search for any third pary jar file which already implemented dialog box.