# How can I show dialog box on canvas in J2ME mobile application?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lcdui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this possible to use lwuit.Dialog with javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas in wireless toolkit 2.5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641839/is-this-possible-to-use-lwuit-dialog-with-javax-microedition-lcdui-canvas-in-wir)

I created a canvas to write contents when I press mobile keys(for Example if I press "A" it will be written on the screen using paint function). Now I want to show a dialog or PopUp window when I press any key from mobile. Is it possible to show dialog when am using Canvas?

say some example,

```
   public class Mycanvas extends Canvas implement ActionListener
   {
     Dialog dialog=new Dialog();

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think you must do that. The right thing in LWUIT is using `Dialog`.

Create a `Dialog` using `new`. i.e. `Dialog d = new Dialog()`

The next step is filling the title and body with `Dialog.setTitle(String text)` or putting something inside the `Dialog`'s layout.

When your `Dialog` is ready to be shown, you must call to `Dialog.show()` and when you want to  remove it, call to `Dialog.dispose()`

Take a look here

[Is this possible to use lwuit.Dialog with javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas in wireless toolkit 2.5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641839/is-this-possible-to-use-lwuit-dialog-with-javax-microedition-lcdui-canvas-in-wir)

Answer (score 0):

If it is for debugging purpose you can use Alert instead. Here's an example how you can use Alert:

```
//you need to import javax.microedition.lcdui;
Alert alert = new Alert("Info", "Here's the key code/string", null, AlertType.INFO);
alert.setTimeout(3000);    // for 3 seconds
display.setCurrent(alert, yourcanvasname);    // so that it goes to back to your canvas after displaying the alert
```

Alert works fine with both forms and canvases.

Comment: If you are using LWUIT lib, the right thing would be to use Dialog